# Removing white space from db result in LINQ query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm attempting to remove white space from a post code field in a database so that when I compare it to the users input I'm comparing both strings with no spaces in the post code at all so it shouldn't matter how the post code is entered.

This is my LINQ query with the replace function that doesn't appear to be working:

```
List<SchoolReferanceDTO> res = db.SchoolReferences.Where(x => x.SchoolReferencePostcode.Replace(" ", "").Contains(Postcode)).Select(x => new SchoolReferanceDTO()
                {
                    SchoolReferenceSchoolId = x.SchoolReferenceSchoolId,
                    SchoolReferenceEstablishmentName = x.SchoolReferenceEstablishmentName,
                    SchoolReferenceStreet = x.SchoolReferenceStreet,
                    SchoolReferenceLocality = x.SchoolReferenceLocality,
                    SchoolReferenceAddress3 = x.SchoolReferenceAddress3,
                    SchoolReferenceTown = x.SchoolReferenceTown,
                    SchoolReferenceCounty = x.SchoolReferenceCounty,
                    SchoolReferencePostcode = x.SchoolReferencePostcode,
                    SchoolReferenceEmail = x.SchoolReferenceEmail
                }).ToList();
```

And the string I'm comparing it to:

```
postcode = postcode.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
```

Comment: And do you have some data samples? Did you debug and checked what the values are at runtime?

Comment: I did yeah - I've tried with the post code "ST14BJ" which doesn't work and this is compared to "ST1 4BJ" in the database

Comment: Try using your Replace in a Select first and then chain with your Where.

Comment: The example at the bottom suggests it should be `Contains(postcode)`, not `Contains(Postcode)`. Is uppercase `P` a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to drop `Replace`, and use `LIKE` instead. Since postal codes are generally short, you could transform the target code `ST14BJ` to `%S%T%1%4%B%J%` ([demo](https://ideone.com/2UF97R)), and use `LIKE` operator:

```
var postPattern = Regex.Replace(postcode, "(?<=.|^)(?=.|$)", "%");
List<SchoolReferanceDTO> res = db.SchoolReferences
    .Where(x => SqlFunctions.PatIndex(postPattern, x.SchoolReferencePostcode) >= 0)
    .Select(...);
```

Comment: This isn't reliable and matches more gregariously than desired, sadly. You can be missing postcode characters and it'll still match.